# Knapsack C# implementation task

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to write knapsack c# algorithm with given conditions but there's always two problems i encountering. I'm getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error or my result is just 0.

I found couple code examples of Knapsack implementation and just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Code examples:
https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/knapsack-problem

http://www.csharpstar.com/csharp-knapsack-problem/

My code:

```
static int Knapsack(int n, int w, int[] s, int[] v)
{
    int[,] G = new int[n+1,w+1];
    for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < w; r++)
        {
            if (r == 0 || k == 0)
                G[k, r] = 0;
            else if (s[k] <= r)
                G[k, r] = Math.Max(G[k- 1, r], v[k] + G[k - 1, r - s[k]]);
            else
                G[k, r] = G[k - 1, r]; 
        }
    }
    return G[n, w];
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] s = { 60, 100, 120};
    int[] v = { 10, 20, 30 };
    int w = 50;
    int n = s.Length;
    Console.WriteLine(Knapsack(n, w, s, v));
}
```

In this case my result is 0.

Comment: It would help if you could set breakpoints to determine on what line and what variable throws the out of range exception.

Comment: If `n` is meant to be the size of the `s` array then just use `s.Length` in your method instead of passing in `n`.  Passing in array sizes is not necessary in C# like it is in C++ and C.  In fact a simple class with weight and value properties will get this down to just one array of that class type and the max weight.

Comment: With the given values `(s[k] <= r)` will never be true.

Comment: In that first example it has the second `for` loop as `for (int w = 0; w <= capacity; ++w)` which would be `for(int r = 0; r <= w; r++)` in your code.  Notice it has `<=` and you have `<`.  This also illustrates a dire need for better variable names.

Comment: Also the `else if` is `K[i, w] = Math.Max(value[i - 1] + K[i - 1, w - weight[i - 1]], K[i - 1, w]);` which should be `G[k,r] = Math.Max(s[k-1] + G[k-1, r - v[k-1]], G[k-1, r])` in your code, but you have `v[k] + G[k-1, r - s[k]]` instead of `s[k-1] + G[k-1, r - v[k-1]]`.

Comment: @juharr i don't know if you noticed but i'm given specific conditions. So I think that i wrote them correctly :/

Comment: Why would you think you've written it correctly when you get the wrong answer?  Specificlly `r` represents a weight and `v` is a set of values so why would you subtract a value from a weight.  Also your definition is missing explanations for what the letters represent.

Comment: @juharr The main thing is that task don't clarify what is r or v. From what  i got i think that v is weight and s is set of values.

Comment: I think your first mistake is trying to use the same meaningless names in the mathematical definition.  That makes the code very very difficult to understand.

Comment: OK I see your problem.  Your code treats `s` as the weights and `v` as the values, but in the examples the values are the other way round.  Thus you can never fit items with weights of 60, 100, and 120 into a capacity of 50.  Again I cannot stress enough how important meaningful names can be to figuring out problems like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `s` is the weights and `v` is the values and your weights of 60, 100, and 120 will obvious not fit into a capacity of 50, that's why you get a result of 0.  The example you pull those values from set's the 60, 100, and 120 as the values and 10, 20, and 30 as the weights which is why it gets a result of 220.

I think this works better if you create a class to handle the related weight and value for the items.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then the method only needs an array of items and the desired capacity. Also using meaningful names can make understanding what's going on easier than a bunch of single letter names.

```
public static int KnapSack(Item[] items, int capacity)
{
    int[,] matrix = new int[items.Length + 1, capacity + 1];
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex <= items.Length; itemIndex++)
    {
        // This adjusts the itemIndex to be 1 based instead of 0 based
        // and in this case 0 is the initial state before an item is
        // considered for the knapsack.
        var currentItem = itemIndex == 0 ? null : items[itemIndex - 1];
        for (int currentCapacity = 0; currentCapacity <= capacity; currentCapacity++)
        {
            // Set the first row and column of the matrix to all zeros
            // This is the state before any items are added and when the
            // potential capacity is zero the value would also be zero.
            if (currentItem == null || currentCapacity == 0)
            {
                matrix[itemIndex, currentCapacity] = 0;
            }
            // If the current items weight is less than the current capacity
            // then we should see if adding this item to the knapsack 
            // results in a greater value than what was determined for
            // the previous item at this potential capacity.
            else if (currentItem.Weight <= currentCapacity)
            {
                matrix[itemIndex, currentCapacity] = Math.Max(
                    currentItem.Value 
                        + matrix[itemIndex - 1, currentCapacity - currentItem.Weight],
                    matrix[itemIndex - 1, currentCapacity]);
            }
            // current item will not fit so just set the value to the 
            // what it was after handling the previous item.
            else
            {
                matrix[itemIndex, currentCapacity] = 
                    matrix[itemIndex - 1, currentCapacity];
            }
        }
    }

    // The solution should be the value determined after considering all
    // items at all the intermediate potential capacities.
    return matrix[items.Length, capacity];
}
```

Then running this code

```
var items = new[]
{
    new Item {Value = 60, Weight = 10},
    new Item {Value = 100, Weight = 20},
    new Item {Value = 120, Weight = 30},
};

Console.WriteLine(KnapSack(items, 50));
```

results in 220.

Here's a solution that uses recursion.

```
public static int KnapSackRecursive(Item[] items, int capacity)
{
    // If there are no items or capacity is 0 then return 0
    if (items.Length == 0 || capacity == 0) return 0;

    // If there is one item and it fits then return it's value
    // otherwise return 0
    if (items.Length == 1)
    {
        return items[0].Weight < capacity ? items[0].Value : 0;
    }

    // keep track of the best value seen.
    int best = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        // This is an array of the other items.
        var otherItems = items.Take(i).Concat(items.Skip(i + 1)).ToArray();

        // Calculate the best value without using the current item.
        int without = KnapSackRecursive(otherItems, capacity);
        int with = 0;

        // If the current item fits then calculate the best value for
        // a capacity less it's weight and with it removed from contention
        // and add the current items value to that.
        if (items[i].Weight <= capacity)
        {
            with = KnapSackRecursive(otherItems, capacity - items[i].Weight) 
                + items[i].Value;
        }

        // The current best is the max of the with or without.
        int currentBest = Math.Max(without, with);

        // determine if the current best is the overall best.
        if (currentBest > best)
            best = currentBest;
    }

    return best;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry if it was difficult to understand. I'm not really good at programming. Could you explain `var currentItem = itemIndex == 0 ? null : items[itemIndex - 1];` syntax?

Comment: Basically that checks if `itemIndex` is  zero if it is then it sets `currentItem` to `null` otherwise it sets it to `items[itemIndex - 1]`.  Basically `x = condition ? this : that;` is short hand for `if(condition) x = this; else x = that;`  It's called the conditional operator or some call it the ternary operator because it's the only operator that takes 3 operands.

Comment: Last question,what if I would do this using recursion maybe you know or can suggest some examples?

Comment: @Ekli I've added a recursive solution.

Comment: The recoursive solution can be optimized replacing "best = currentBest" with a simple "return currentBest"; this shuould avoid looking for a better solution in the subset of elements because you already found one. You've been looking for the best not considering current weight and the best without considering it; ther's no need to continue if you just found a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Complete example of Knapsack problem using `C# 12` in `.NET 8`. Tested using `NUnit 3`.

#### Problem

Suppose you’re going camping. You have a knapsack that holds **6 lb**, and you can take the following items. They each have a value, and the higher the value, the more important the item is:

| Item | Weight (lb) | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WATER | 3 | 10 |
| BOOK | 1 | 3 |
| FOOD | 2 | 9 |
| JACKET | 2 | 5 |
| CAMERA | 1 | 6 |

What’s the optimal set of items to take on your camping trip?

#### Creating Dynamic-programming grid

Draw the dynamic-programming grid for the above list of items.

Read the explanation on 3rd row to understand how the grid is filled.

*The table is horizontally scrollable.*

| _____________ | 0 lb ____________ | 1 lb ____________ | 2 lb ___________________________ | 3 lb ___________________________ | 4 lb ___________________________ | 5 lb ___________________________ | 6 lb ___________________________ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WATER (W) Weight: 3 lb Value: 10 | 0 *(0,0)* [] | 0 *(0,1)* [] | 0 *(0,2)* [] | 10 *(0,3)* [W] | 10 *(0,4)* [W] | 10 *(0,5)* [W] | 10 *(0,6)* [W] |
| BOOK (B) Weight: 1 lb Value: 3 | 0 *(1,0)* [] | 3 *(1,1)* [B] | 3 *(1,2)* [B] | 10 *(1,3)* [W] | 13 *(1,4)* [BW] | 13 *(1,5)* [BW] | 13 *(1,6)* [BW] |
| FOOD (F) Weight: 2 lb Value: 9 | 0 *(2,0)* Does FOOD fit here? If No, just grab the cell from right above. [] | 3 *(2,1)* Does FOOD fit here? If No, just grab the cell from right above. [B] | 9 *(2,2)* Does FOOD fit here? If Yes, do below calculation. = MAX (Prev Max:Right above it, Current value + Remaining space value) = MAX (3, 9 + (2 lb - 2 lb)) = MAX (3, 9 + value at (1,0)) = MAX (3, 9 + 0) = MAX (3, 9) = 9 [F] | 12 *(2,3)* Does FOOD fit here? If Yes, do below calculation. = MAX (Prev Max:Right above it, Current value + Remaining space value) = MAX (10, 9 + (3 lb - 2 lb)) = MAX (10, 9 + value at (1,1)) = MAX (10, 9 + 3) = MAX (10, 12) = 12 [FB] | 13 *(2,4)* Does FOOD fit here? If Yes, do below calculation. = MAX (Prev Max:Right above it, Current value + Remaining space value) = MAX (13, 9 + (4 lb - 2 lb)) = MAX (13, 9 + value at (1,2)) = MAX (13, 9 + 3) = MAX (13, 12) = 13 [BW] | 19 *(2,5)* Does FOOD fit here? If Yes, do below calculation. = MAX (Prev Max:Right above it, Current value + Remaining space value) = MAX (13, 9 + (5 lb - 2 lb)) = MAX (13, 9 + value at (1,3)) = MAX (13, 9 + 10) = MAX (13, 19) = 19 [FW] | 22 *(2,6)* Does FOOD fit here? If Yes, do below calculation. = MAX (Prev Max:Right above it, Current value + Remaining space value) = MAX (13, 9 + (6 lb - 2 lb)) = MAX (13, 9 + value at (1,4)) = MAX (13, 9 + 13) = MAX (13, 22) = 22 [FBW] |
| JACKET (J) Weight: 2 lb Value: 5 | 0 *(3,0)* [] | 3 *(3,1)* [B] | 9 *(3,2)* [F] | 12 *(3,3)* [FB] | 14 *(3,4)* [FJ] | 19 *(3,5)* [FW] | 22 *(3,6)* [FBW] |
| CAMERA (C) Weight: 1 lb Value: 6 | 0 *(4,0)* [] | 6 *(4,1)* [C] | 9 *(4,2)* [F] | 15 *(4,3)* [FC] | 18 *(4,4)* [FBC] | 20 *(4,5)* [FJC] | 25 *(4,6)* [FWC] |

#### Implementing the grid in code

```cs
namespace Algorithms.DynamicProgramming;

public record Item(string Name, int Weight, int Value);
public record GridCell(int Value, List<Item> Items);

public static class KnapsackSolver
{
    public static GridCell[,] Solve(Item[] items, int maxCapacity)
    {
        // 2 dimensional array of GridCells with items.Length rows and (maxCapacity + 1) columns
        var grid = new GridCell[items.Length, maxCapacity + 1];

        for (var row = 0; row < items.Length; row++)
        {
            for (var capacity = 0; capacity <= maxCapacity; capacity++)
            {
                // The first row is special. It kinda sets the stage for everything that follows.
                if (row == 0)
                {
                    // The item fits
                    if (items[row].Weight <= capacity)
                    {
                        grid[row, capacity] = new GridCell(items[row].Value, [items[row]]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grid[row, capacity] = new GridCell(0, []);
                    }
                }
                // For the rest of the rows
                // The item fits
                else if (items[row].Weight <= capacity)
                {
                    var item = items[row]; // Item under test
                    var valueInRemainingSpace = grid[row - 1, capacity - item.Weight].Value;
                    var valueIfTaken = item.Value + valueInRemainingSpace;
                    var valueIfNotTaken = grid[row - 1, capacity].Value; // Previous Max
                    if (valueIfTaken > valueIfNotTaken)
                    {
                        var itemsInRemainingSpace = grid[row - 1, capacity - item.Weight].Items;
                        // Note: List.Add modifies original data, but List.Append returns new array without modifying original data
                        grid[row, capacity] = new GridCell(valueIfTaken, itemsInRemainingSpace.Append(item).ToList());
                    }
                    // If you don't take the new value (valueIfTaken), just grab the cell from right above
                    else
                    {
                        grid[row, capacity] = grid[row - 1, capacity];
                    }
                }
                // The item doesn't fit, so grab the cell from right above
                else
                {
                    grid[row, capacity] = grid[row - 1, capacity];
                }
            }
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

#### Testing the code

```cs
using NUnit.Framework;
using Algorithms.DynamicProgramming;

namespace Algorithms.UnitTests.DynamicProgramming;

public class KnapsackSolverTests
{
    [Test]
    public void KnapsackSolver_Finds_Optimal_Set_Of_Items()
    {
        // Arrange
        var maxCapacity = 6;
        Item[] items =
        [
            new Item("Water", 3, 10),
            new Item("Book", 1, 3),
            new Item("Food", 2, 9),
            new Item("Jacket", 2, 5),
            new Item("Camera", 1, 6)
        ];
        
        // Act
        var grid = KnapsackSolver.Solve(items, maxCapacity);
        
        var optimalItems = grid[items.Length - 1, maxCapacity].Items.Select(i => i.Name);
        var optimalValue = grid[items.Length - 1, maxCapacity].Value;
        
        // Assert
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] {"Food", "Water", "Camera"}, optimalItems);
        Assert.That(optimalValue, Is.EqualTo(25));
    }
}
```

[image]