# Given a list of strings, distribute into two 100 character fields

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am not sure what's the best way to ask this question so please bear with me.

I have a legacy platform that has 2x 100 varchar fields for holding delimited email addresses.

I want to take a `List<String>` and distribute it into the two fields in such a way that I can add the maximum number of items. Obviously the email addresses are varying lengths, and a delimiter of ";MAPI:" has to be added between entries.The sequence does not matter and the only requirement for field2 is that field1 has at least a single entry.

This new method would be called when a user tries to add a new address to the list, so it is entirely possible that the new item can not fit in any arrangement in which case I would simply tell the user that the field can not accept an address of that length.

I tried ordering by length and adding items into field1 until it is full then adding the remainder to field2 but that is not "optimal" because if I left one or more of the short entries for field2 then a long entry could potentially better fill field1

Comment: Can an email address be splitted between two different char[100] items? Or they should be fitted entirely?

Comment: @IliaMaskov no, the entire address must fit

Comment: Looks like it's a one-dimensional knapsack problem which is NP-hard, so you can only optimize solution by effective time for example using dynamic programming.

Comment: @IliaMaskov Would you add your comment as an answer because even though I do not have the knapsack problem resolved, it is the correct name for the issue and has given me the directional push I was needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a one-dimensional knapsack problem which is NP-hard, so you can only optimize solution by effective time for example using dynamic programming.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: this gave me the directional push i needed, i utilized code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395293/73332 and modified it for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Order them by length, biggest first, add them to the lists alternating between A and B.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented Isitar's algorithm, if it helps.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string form1 = String.Empty, form2 = String.Empty;
    var emails = new List<string> { "biglongemail@email.com", "short@email.com", "mediumsized@email.com"};

    FillForms(ref form1, ref form2, emails);

    Console.WriteLine("form1: " + form1 + "\nform2: " + form2);
}

private static bool HasRoom(string form, string email) {
    return (form + email).Count() <= 100;
}   

private static void FillForms(ref string form1, ref string form2, List<string> inputEmails)
{
    List<string> emails = inputEmails.OrderBy(email => email.Count()).ToList();

    string delim = String.Empty;
    bool full = false;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < emails.Count && !full)
    {
        full = true;

        if (HasRoom(form1, emails[i]))
        {
            form1 += delim + emails[i];
            full = false;
            i++;
            if (i >= emails.Count()) break;
        }


        if (HasRoom(form2, emails[i]))
        {
            form2 += delim + emails[i];             
            full = false;
            i++;
        }   


        delim = ";MAPI:";
    }
```

[Dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KsOqaQ)