# How to convert recursive algorithm to dynamic programming?

Tags: c#, recursion, dynamic-programming, recursion-schemes

I have this algorithm:

```
static int findMaxRec(int[] w, int[] v, int W, int n)
{
    int max = int.MinValue;
    int res;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] <= W)
        {
            if (w[i] == W)
                res = v[i]; // F(0) + v[i] = v[i]
            else
                res = findMaxRec(w, v, W - w[i], n) + v[i];

            max = max < res ? res : max;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

How can I convert it to dynamic programming algorithm?
I have tried several ideas but none of them seems to work. So I am stuck.

P.S. w and v are just simple number arrays, nothing fancier. W is just a number. This algorithm does not implement any particular task I just found it in a book where they ask to implement algorithms for given formulas.

UPDATE:

```
static int findMaxDyn(int[] F, int[] w, int[] v, int W, int n)
{
    int max = int.MinValue;
    int res;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] <= W)
        {
            if (F[W - w[i]] == int.MinValue) // calculate only if -inf
            {
                if (w[i] == W)
                    res = v[i]; // F(0) + v[i] = v[i]
                else
                    res = findMaxDyn(F, w, v, W - w[i], n) + v[i];

                max = max < res ? res : max;
                F[W - w[i]] = max;
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

This gives wrong answers that do not match to recursive algorithm. And it seems to still use recursion...

Recursion tree that I have drawn when

```
int [] w = new []{ 4, 3, 2, 1};
int [] v = new []{ 4, 3, 2, 1};    
int W = 4;
int n = 4;
```

[image: recursion tree]

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically went wrong with this attempt? As a side note you may want to choose better variable names to make things easier.

Comment: What's the problem this algorithm solves?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I could be wrong but this looks like a solution to some variation of the knap sack problem.

Comment: What is your definition of "dynamic programming"? Does that mean you wan to eliminate the recursion in favor of an iterative approach?

Comment: Btw, this doesn't check for malicious input , where n >= w.Length or v.Length.

Comment: As I have mentioned, I am not sure what task does it solve. I will add recursion tree that I have drawn it might clarify things a bit @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: @tnw Mathematical programming frequently uses variable names to match the typically used variables in the mathematical expressions.  It may not be clear to a typical developer, but for the developer that is versed in the mathematics of the algorithm it is often not a bad design choice to use variables that match the standard mathematical terms.  I'm not sure if that's the case here, of course...

Comment: @J... while that's correct, it doesn't apply here, because OP is absolutely oblivious about the mathematics. And so are we. It is unknown, what problem is adressed, it is unknown what restrictions apply to the input vectors ...

Comment: @Fildor Nevertheless, that only means that OP wouldn't really have any better name to give them other than the ones used in the text which presents the algorithm - you have to know what something is before you can give it a useful name.  For those who would be familiar with this algorithm, however, seeing code that used the standard variable names would be readable, even if the original code author did not understand the labels.

Comment: While you are right those are prefaced by comment that explain the variable name like `// Input:
// Values (stored in array v)
// Weights (stored in array w)
// Number of distinct items (n)
// Knapsack capacity (W)` Without any comment on naming the variable name must speak for themself.

Comment: @J... again, I agree with you. But then, I'd figure OP is not fit (has not done enough research) to even _start_ with what they are trying to do.

Comment: @Fildor True, but beside the point.

Comment: As stated above, what you seem to be trying to solve is known as the "knapsack problem". This might be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50395293/10608418

Comment: Thank you all, at least I now know that I am solving a knapsack problem! It actually is a task from my university and all they gave us was recurent formula and told us to program a recursive and dynammic algoritms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know what the algorithm is trying to do but the non-recursive function could be:

```cs
   public static int findMaxRec_NonRecursive(int[] Vect_w, int[] Vect_v, int W, int n)
        {
           
            List<int> prevWValues = new List<int>();
            List<int> prevVValues = new List<int>();
            List<int> prevIndex_i = new List<int>();
            List<int> prevMaxValue = new List<int>();
            int ListIndex = 0, iniIndex = 0, max = int.MinValue;

            startOver:
            
            for (int i = iniIndex; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (Vect_w[i] <= W)
                {                   
                    if (Vect_w[i] == W)                        
                        max = Math.Max(Vect_v[i], max);
                    else
                    {
                        if (prevWValues.Count > ListIndex)
                        {
                            prevWValues[ListIndex] = W;
                            prevIndex_i[ListIndex] = i;
                            prevVValues[ListIndex] = Vect_v[i];
                            prevMaxValue[ListIndex] = max;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prevWValues.Add(W);
                            prevIndex_i.Add(i);
                            prevVValues.Add(Vect_v[i]);
                            prevMaxValue.Add(max);
                        }
                        W -= Vect_w[i];
                        ListIndex++;
                        iniIndex = 0;                       
                        max = int.MinValue;
                        goto startOver;
                    }                   
                }
            }

           
            if (ListIndex>0)
            {
                ListIndex--;
                iniIndex = prevIndex_i[ListIndex]+1;
                W = prevWValues[ListIndex];  
                max = Math.Max(max+ prevVValues[ListIndex], prevMaxValue[ListIndex]);
                goto startOver;
            }    
           
            return max;
        }
```

Sorry for the 'gotos', I just found it easier to program for this case. Also I have renamed a little your input variables not to drive crazy.

**EDIT**

As others have pointed out, it could be used as a Knapsack algorithm, so knowing what it is intended to do, you could optimize/simplify a little more (the complexity of these kind of algorithms grow exponentially with *n*). For instance, you can sort the input Vect_W values and replace lists by arrays.

```cs
 public static int findMaxRec_NonRecursive(int[] Vect_w, int[] Vect_v, int W, int n)
        {
            Array.Sort(Vect_w, Vect_v);
            n = Math.Min(n, Vect_w.Length);

            //Remove here repeated elements in Vect_w selecting the one with higher Vect_v if uniqueness is not assured

            int minVectW = Vect_w[0];

            int L = W / minVectW + 1;
            int[] prevWValues = new int[L];
            int[] prevVValues = new int[L];
            int[] prevIndex_i = new int[L];
            int[] prevMaxValue = new int[L];
            int ListIndex = 0, iniIndex = n - 1, max = int.MinValue, PrevUsefullIndex = 0;            

            startOver:

            for (int i = iniIndex; i >= 0; i--)
            {                
                if (Vect_w[i] <= W)
                {
                    if (PrevUsefullIndex < i)
                        PrevUsefullIndex = i;

                    if (Vect_w[i] == W)
                        max = Math.Max(Vect_v[i], max);
                    else
                    {
                        int newW = W - Vect_w[i];
                        if (newW < minVectW)
                            max = Math.Max(Vect_v[i], max);
                        else
                        {
                            prevWValues[ListIndex] = W;
                            prevIndex_i[ListIndex] = i;
                            prevVValues[ListIndex] = Vect_v[i];
                            prevMaxValue[ListIndex] = max;

                            W = newW;                       
                            ListIndex++;
                            iniIndex = PrevUsefullIndex;
                            PrevUsefullIndex = 0;
                            max = int.MinValue;
                            goto startOver;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (ListIndex > 0)
            {
                ListIndex--;
                iniIndex = prevIndex_i[ListIndex] - 1;
                W = prevWValues[ListIndex];
                max = Math.Max(max + prevVValues[ListIndex], prevMaxValue[ListIndex]);
                goto startOver;
            }

            return max;
        }
```

**EDIT 2**

I just found out that the initial recursive algorithm posted is not well conditioned, for example in the case where the best branch is the first branch. I think it should have an additional condition to avoid that:

```cs
   //[...]
   else
    {          
            int innerMax = findMaxRec(w, v, W - w[i], n);
            if (innerMax == int.MinValue)
                 innerMax = 0;
            res = innerMax + v[i];

     }

   //[...]
```

I have also added a condition in the  non-recursive algorithm that does pretty much the same by checking if the branch can be officialy closed when the new W is lower than the smallest vect_W element.

Comment: Thank you! Now I at least have a clue about what I am doing.

Comment: I also think that it actually is a knapsack problem as others mentioned before. I was just given a task where some information was not mentioned so it was difficult to understand.